# Why my console-based c++ game doesn't run on the other windows machines? (returns missing .dll errors)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, compiler-errors, g++

I have made a simple console-based C++ Tic-Tac-Toe game, which has to be compiled with this command to properly work:

```
"E:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "E:\My Apps\C++\Projects\TTT-game\TTT-Game.cpp" -o "E:\My Apps\C++\Projects\TTT-game\TTT-Game.exe" -lWinmm -lGdi32
```

I show the command because I also wanted to mention that I am linking to additional libraries just for you to keep that in mind.

When I run this on my own PC, it works just as expected, however, when I share the game folder with a friend, they have to re-compile the `.cpp` file! and running the same compiled-to `.exe` file, returns errors such as:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++-6.dll AND libgcc_s_seh-1.dll AND libwinpthread-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

What I need, is to let whoever runs the `.exe` file to be able to play the game. It is alright if the game files have to be in the same folder(although it could also be better if you can suggest me a way to put the files inside the `.exe` file itself).

How can I go about this?

Comment: Static build, or use Windows libraries. Or cmake + build script so the build isn't locked into your specific environment. Or go whole hog and create an installer (unlikey given the project). Not everyone installs MinGW on their machines. And are you saying you **have** to create a debug build in order for it to work?

Comment: Add `-static` to the command line. Your executable will likely increase dramatically in size, but the standard library implementation will be built in.

Comment: You could just create an installer for your game like most commercial software does. nsis or WIX are not that difficult.

Comment: Hey! sorry that i reply so late but here i am! 1. Not exactly, i put the command there just to show you that i'm also linking libraries to the game. 2. I just tried the `-static` flag and yeah it's now 2 MG, i have to test it to be sure it works. 3. Yeah i'd like to learn how to make setups for the games, how can i go about it? i looked it up a couple times didn't get such great results.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! using the `-static` flag worked and my friend can now play the game!!! however i'm still wondering something... if i can kinda embed the files into the `.exe` file itself... and if i can create a setup for the game, if u guys can help me out on these, that'd be awesome! :)